# Apply Spring paging to a dynamically created query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

If I have a Spring repository, I can get paged results by defining a method in the following way (for example):

```java
@Query("<some JPAQL here>")
Page<Person> findBySomething(String foo, String bar, Pageable pageable);
```

I'd like to do the same, only to create the query dynamically (the query itself differs slightly based on some input data). Something like:

```java
String queryString = "<JPAQL part1>";
if (condition) queryString += "<JPAQL part2>";
queryString += "<JPAQL part3>";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
query.setParameter("foo", foo);
query.setParameter("bar", bar);
return query.getResultListAndApplySpringPaging(pageable);
```

I do *not* want to rewrite my query to either Querydsl or Criteria API. In part because I don't want to spend time on that and in part because my JPAQL contains some Oracle-specific stuff which might be difficult, if not impossible, to express in them (e.g. things like `ORDER BY NLSSORT(t.displayValue, 'NLS_SORT = XCZECH') ASC`).

Is there a way to manually pass a `String` or a `javax.persistence.Query` through Spring's paging mechanism?

Comment: Why don't you also create the `Pageable` while constructing your query?

Comment: @daniu: I'm afraid I don't understand. I do have the `Pageable`. The question now is how to use it. (Now that I look at it, the last line should be something like `return query.getResultListAndApplySpringPaging(pageable)` but it was supposed to be only for illustration anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after debugging Spring internals for a while, I have something resembling a solution. It skips a lot of things Spring does (which means it's not as general) but at least for simple situations it seems to be working for me.

```java
String queryString = dynamicallyComposeQueryForConditions(someConditions);
String countQueryString = QueryUtils.createCountQueryFor(queryString);
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
Query countQuery = entityManager.createQuery(countQueryString);
query.setParameter("foo", foo);
query.setParameter("bar", bar);
countQuery.setParameter("foo", foo);
countQuery.setParameter("bar", bar);
query.setFirstResult((int) pageable.getOffset());
query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(query.getResultList(), pageable,
        () -> (long) countQuery.getSingleResult());
```

Obviously, there's room for improvement. First of all, both queries need to have the same parameters set which shouldn't be done the way I do it here for simplicity reasons. Second of all, `getPage` is quite clever to execute the `countQuery` (or more precisely the `totalSupplier`) only if it is needed (which isn't always). Which means that even calling `QueryUtils.createCountQueryFor(queryString)` and then `entityManager.createQuery(countQueryString)` isn't always necessary and should actually be done only inside the `totalSupplier`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you create 2 methods: one with part2, one without it and then call the proper one based on the condition.

```
@Query("<part part3>")
Page<Person> findBySomething(String foo, String bar, Pageable pageable);

@Query("<part1 part2 part3>")
Page<Person> findBySomethingElse(String foo, String bar, Pageable pageable);

...

return condition?findBySomethingElse(foo, bar, pageable):findBySomething(foo, bar, pageable);
```

Comment: Well yes, if there was only one such condition, I could do this. The problem is that there could easily be five or ten conditions based on which I'm creating the final query.